# Constraint Layout with Viewpager2 occuping full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a problem with Constraint Layout which is occupying whole screen, i.e; overlapping my other views to and below is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/appTourViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/appTourIndicator"/>

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator3
        android:id="@+id/appTourIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        app:ci_drawable="@drawable/circle_radius_selected"
        app:ci_drawable_unselected="@drawable/circle_radius_unselected"
        app:ci_height="6dp"
        app:ci_margin="5dp"
        app:ci_width="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/appTourViewPager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSignIn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnGetStartedNow" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGetStartedNow"
        style="@style/Button.Blue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/getStartedNow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is a solution for your problem

You need to give bottom constraint for `ViewPager` and make `height` as `0dp` for `ViewPager`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/appTourViewPager"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/appTourIndicator"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/appTourIndicator"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator3
            android:id="@+id/appTourIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            app:ci_drawable="@drawable/circle_radius_selected"
            app:ci_drawable_unselected="@drawable/circle_radius_unselected"
            app:ci_height="6dp"
            app:ci_margin="5dp"
            app:ci_width="6dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/appTourViewPager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSignIn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnGetStartedNow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGetStartedNow"
            style="@style/Button.Blue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/getStartedNow"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ViewPager 2 `layout_height` should be `match constraints` instead of `match_parent`.

To do that set `layout_height="0dp"` and add `top`, `bottom` constraints to ViewPager 2

ex:

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 
    ...
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSignIn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    ...
/>
```